# Best practices for Media Player stop on disappear?

Tags: objective-c

I have a tabbed application in which some view controllers have an embedded video player. 
For obvious reasons, I want to stop the video when the user move to another tab (otherwise, it continue playing in background).

In iOS 5, I had implemented this in the viewDidDisappear on the view controller. However, since iOS 6, it seems that the full screen mode of the media player makes the underlying view to "disappear". So, my video stops 1sec after I press the full screen button.

So my question is: what are the best practices to stop the video when moving out from the media player container, while keeping support for full-screen mode?

Comment: On tab change ? Quite "heavy" solution (in terms of code)

Comment: Actually, there is no notification on tab change (only a delegate). And the player notification do not help me in this case.

Comment: Well no. You would post your own notification when there is a tab change and observe/listen for that notification in the view controllers that have an embedded player.